# get CSS Property values using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-rc

**How to get the property value of a CSS class using selnium RC**

I tried it using webdriver but can't get what is required

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`getEval(String script)`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.8.1/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getEval%28java.lang.String%29) command to evaluate javascript to fetch the property.

Selenium can be pretty limited in this sense

EDIT:

`this.style.someAttribute` will give you the value of `someAttribute` css style for the given Selenium node.

Also, if you want to run JavaScript on elements within the document body, such as `document.getElementById` .., you need to preceed your JavaScript string with "this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()".  For example, if I wanted to get the innerHTML of the element with id 'page_title', I would call

```
String title = getEval("this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById('page_title').innerHTML");
```

This will evaluate the JavaScript in the context of the window you are testing.  Failure to include this will execute JavaScript within the context of the Selenium frame.  *See* [this documentation on the Selenium API](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getEval(java.lang.String)).

Comment: How to get CSS using java Script