# WebElement.getCssValue & WebElement.getAttribute Usage

Tags: selenium

Can anybody help me about how to use these two functions to get value of any CSS property.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? [`WebElement.getCssValue()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue%28java.lang.String%29) returns a value of the element's CSS attribute. `String bgColor = driver.findElement(By.id("myId")).getCssValue("background-color");`

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com - read these please. Context would help here. Post what you've tried, otherwise we've not got a clue what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks For ur concern Slanec and Arran
Actually I wanted to check if any Label is Bold or not .For that I tried to check CSS property(font-weight: bold).But I was not able to use these funtions in eclipse(testNG) as my class is already extending one class.So Please suggest upon
1.How to use WebElement.getCssValue & WebElement.getAttribute in Eclipse(TestNG) 
2.Can font verification(Bold) be done with these two Functions.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452790/how-to-using-webdriver-selenium-to-get-the-value-of-style-element/20065390#20065390

Answer (score 5):

If have a particular `<img>` tag as below

```
<img title="Title" alt="myTitle" src="A/B/C/xyz.png">
```

`driver.getElement(By.tagName("img")).getAttribute("src")` will get you the `src` attribute of this tag. Result - `A/B/C/xyz.png`

Similarly, you can get the values of attributes such as `title`, `alt` etc.

Similarly you can get CSS properties of any tag by using `getCssValue("some propety")`

Comment: How can we get the attribute using selenium rc rather than WebDriver

Comment: Maybe this question might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201337/how-to-get-attribute-value-using-selenium-and-css

Comment: I need to get the attribute of the css class but not the html element.Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578900/get-css-property-values-using-selenium