# How to Using Webdriver Selenium to get the value of "style" element

Tags: java, selenium

I want to check whether the value of a style element is greater than a particular value (i.e., is left > 666px ?), but I am unable to get ahold of the value.

Here is the HTML code of the style that I want to capture:

```
<pre><span id="da2c" style="left: 666px; top: 27px;"></pre>
```

I am using this code to try to print its value, but it's not printing:

```
System.out.print(driver.findElement(By.id("da1c")).findElement(By.cssSelector("span")).getAttribute("style"));
```

I want something like this:

```
if ((driver.findElement(By.id("da1c")).findElement(By.cssSelector("span")).getAttribute("style")).value> 700) {
  System.out.println("value exceeding")
}
```

Answer (score 22):

You may capture the Computed Css value as shown in the firebug screenshot below:

[image]

like this:

```
WebDriver web = new FirefoxDriver(;
String visibility = web.findElement(By.xpath("//your xpath")).getCssValue("display");
```

Answer (score 11):

If you execute `.getAttribute("style")` on that span, you will recieve a String.

`left: 666px; top: 27px;`
You can use string manipulation to fetch a particular style.

Alternatively, you can execute some javascript magic using the JavaScriptExecutor, and fetching the `left` value directly by

```
String script = "var thing = window.document.getElementById('da2c'); 
                             window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(thing, null).getPropertyValue('left');";
```

and then check it from there.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this @SohaibMaroof?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.locator( yourLocator )).getAttribute( requiredAttribute )
```

It will return String