# Selenium test (selection of element having no attribute)

Tags: html, selenium

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>Sample</head>
<body>
<div class="panelBody"> 
  <div class=panel-section></div>
  <div class=panel-section style="display:block"></div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

In given Snippet there are two elements with same class. I have to select the element which does not having style attribute.If i tried to search with panel-section class its giving ambiguity error.So how to select div element which does not having style attribute.i.e

```
                  <div class=panel-section></div>
```

Comment: It can be taken, but what you want to do with such element? Do you want to store it anywhere, click on it? I am not sure it will support select operation.

Comment: @mk08 yes i want to click on it.Do you have any solution?

Comment: Get all the elements with class "panel-section" and then loop all of them to find the element the style match what you want. But if that style is too common/same to default, this may not work.

Comment: @KIt Fung here number attribute are different then can we get that webelement on the basis of number of attribute

Comment: if your style is inline , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452790/how-to-using-webdriver-selenium-to-get-the-value-of-style-element)  may help you

Comment: @Kit Fung but i want element which is not having style attribute

Comment: thats much more easy. use check the result for (webElement .getAttribute("style") == null). But remember this only work if the other element is using inline style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98198/discussion-between-avinash-jadhav-and-kit-fung).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are more than one elements with same class name, you need to use Selenium's `driver.findElements()` method. I have tried getting this element, but I wonder if it is clickable. Only element can actually be useful here is text `Sample`.
Check below code. Let me know if it is similar to what you are looking for.

```
 List<WebElement> linksize=null;
 String links[]=null;
linksize = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class=panel-section]")); 
    int linksCount = linksize.size();
    links= new String[linksCount];
    for(int i=0;i<linksCount;i++)
    {

    links[i] = linksize.get(i).getAttribute("style");
    if(links[i].isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("I am div without style");
        linksize.get(i).click();

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//div[@class='panelBody']/div[not(@style)]
```

Explanation:  First find the div with class panelBody, then find child div elements in the panelBody div which doesn't contain @style attribute.

Use findElements method if there are more than one div element without @style attribute, otherwise findElement() method would suffice.

Comment: is it panelBody or panel-section?

Comment: @AvinashJadhav it's panelBody, he doesn't use panel-section on the second div, because in your example it is irrelevant, if you hat several "parent" divs with panelBody class, then you would probably need to do this: //div[@class='panelBody']/div[@class='panel-section' and not(@style)]