# How to get the "none display" html from selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to get some context by using selenium, however I can't just get the "display: none" part content.  I tried use `attribute('innerHTML')` but still not work as expected.

Hope if you could share some knowledge.

[Here is the html][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdDL4.png


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from lxml import etree

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://flights.ctrip.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
element_time = driver.find_element_by_id('DepartDate1TextBox')
element_time.clear()
element_time.send_keys(u'2017-10-22')
element_arr = driver.find_element_by_id('ArriveCity1TextBox')
element_arr.clear()
element_arr.send_keys(u'北京')
element_depart = driver.find_element_by_id('DepartCity1TextBox')
element_depart.clear()
element_depart.send_keys(u'南京')
driver.find_element_by_id('search_btn').click()
time.sleep(1)
print(driver.current_url)
driver.find_element_by_id('btnReSearch').click()
print(driver.current_url)

overlay=driver.find_element_by_id("mask_loading")
print(driver.exeucte_script("return arguments[0].getAttribute('style')",overlay))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Using Webdriver Selenium to get the value of "style" element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452790/how-to-using-webdriver-selenium-to-get-the-value-of-style-element)

Comment: try getAttribute("innerText")  or getAttribute("textContent")

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the attribute "display: none" you can use the following line of code:

```
String my_display = driver.findElement(By.id("mask_loading")).getAttribute("display");
System.out.println("Display attribute is set to : "+my_display);
```

Answer (score 0):

if element style attribute has the value display:none, then it is a hidden element. basically selenium doesn't interact with hidden element. you have to go with javascript executor of selenium to interact with it. You can get the style value as given below.

```
WebElement overlay=driver.findElement(By.id("mask_loading"));

JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor )driver;
String style=je.executeScript("return arguments[0].getAttribute("style");", overlay);
System.out.println("style value of the element is "+style);
```

It prints the value "z-index: 12;display: none;"

or if you want to get the innerHTML,

```
String innerHTML=je.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",overlay);
```

In Python,

```
overlay=driver.find_element_by_id("mask_loading")
style =driver.exeucte_script("return arguments[0].getAttribute('style')",overlay)
```

or

```
innerHTML=driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", overlay)
```

Comment: Thank you Murthi, Good to know. so suppose I'm using the python for it. and now have to turn to the JS to achieve it. would try and let you know !

Comment: In python, there is a method driver.execute_script() and it is equal to executeScript in java

Comment: Hum... I think I tried execute_script() before but it not work for my example. I've just paste out the code I use. the werid thing is I can get correct result of "print(driver.current_url)" but whenever I try print all page content to a file or use driver.find_element_by_id, the expected context begin from div class "flight-list-content" disappear anyway. -_- it looks the web use someway to forbid scratch it.